# iOS Black Magnifying Glass in UITextfield when long press

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am running a x Code 4.6 app in x code 5, and when I am performing a long press event at any text field for editing then a black circle appears? I am not able to understand this problem.

Have anyone came across with this black spot?

Comment: Black spot? Can you post us the screenshot?

Comment: ... if this is what i think it is your just seeing that magnifying glass that helps you move the cursor along text to place it where you want it.

Comment: image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zotmpovgejoqtst/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-28%20at%2011.24.09%20AM.png

Comment: @horsejockey you can see screen shot which i post in comment

Answer (score 1):

Change UIWindow background color to ClearColor.

Answer (score 1):

Some Time 
`[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` Not work.

so add 
`self.window.windowLevel = 1.2;`

in 
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`